# scopeMethods not found in controller PhpStorm Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ide, phpstorm

I'm new to PHP and Laravel so perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I'm following along to Jeffrey Way's Laracasts tutorials and he creates a "query scope" method.

When I then use that in my controller, it says it cant find it.

In my Task model I have:

```
public static function scopeCompleted( Builder $query )
{
    return $query->where( 'completed', 1 );
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
$completed_tasks = Task::completed()->get();
```

but `completed` is highlighted by PhpStorm with the error:

> "Method 'completed' not found in App\Task"

I know it's looking for a method called `scopeCompleted`, but this is not how you call a query scope method in the controller.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a flaw in PhpStorm?

FYI: the code functions perfectly well.

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong or is this just a flaw in PhpStorm?"* There is no PhpStorm flaw here .. unless you will count IDE not knowing how particular framework (Laravel) does his hidden magic as a flaw. You either use already mentioned https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper or (if it cannot help here for some reason) use PHPDoc comment to declare such method (e.g. via `@method` tag -- https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because behind the scenes, Laravel uses magic methods to resolve your scope.

The `completed` method doesn't actually exist in your model, so technically, PHPStorm is correct.

If you want PHPstorm to be able to detect this scope, then install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper into your project.

Comment: Using the ide-helper still does not resolve the scope.